# My Stack Overflow account is deleted

Tags: support, accounts, deleted-users, sock-puppets

I did not delete or recreate my account https://stackoverflow.com/users/13492963/puzzled, but I see there is no question/answer from my history, I have been a member for more than six months for the main site Stack Overflow and also money.stackexchange.com, but today May 7th, 2020, I see it (Stack Overflow) deleted. Can my account be restored?

Here are questions that I have posted:

- *[flutter how to get refreshed firebse's app token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923559/flutter-how-to-get-refreshed-firebses-app-token)*
- *[Curl example with time_to_live(TTL) for fcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407267/curl-example-with-time-to-livettl-for-fcm)*

user12021836

Comment: Your account on SO is from today. You have a account on several other sites which dates back longer. Are you sure you had an account on SO? Do you have any link to a question/answer that you gave?

Comment: @BDL that is not correct, It is showing that way, but I had account on this main site( and also other like money etc) for very long time, my account is some how deleted and then created again and I have not done either

Comment: maybe your account was deleted, then you automatically created it from another account of yours and didn't notice the creation.

Comment: @usr2564301 all my questions and answers on stackoverflow are deleted by someone or some system glitch

Comment: @jean-françois-fabre I did not deleted my account, it seems a system glitch or some admin/hacker

Comment: @BDL see question where I have provided the link

Comment: @dave I have edited the question that lists two questions that I have posted some time ago

Comment: @jean-françois-fabre I added the links to some of my old questions. I did not delete the question

Answer (score 21):

Your old account was detected as a sock-puppet of another account of yours, and therefore was deleted manually by a moderator. So no, your account isn't going to be restored.

Since you have 30+ other accounts on various Stack Exchange sites under that name, you created another one without noticing when switching back to Stack Overflow (and gained 100 rep association bonus again).

Your history shows that you created this account yourself on may 7th by switching from your https://money.stackexchange.com account. This may have been done without noticing, since there is no password or extra info to fill in when you're a trusted network user.

```
User History

Date    Action  Comment     
May 7   add credential  openid.stackexchange.com/user/…     
May 7   user copied profile     from money.stackexchange.com to stackoverflow.com   
May 7   automatically granted association bonus     , Reputation = 100  
May 7   user has been shown legal links and continued
```

You have the right to own multiple accounts on Stack Overflow *as long as they don't interact with each other*. This last rule wasn't respected in that case, and the account with the less reputation/the faker name is deleted.

In that case, the moderator who deleted the account forgot to send a warning to the sock-puppet master account. This is fixed now.

Comment: I see a market for a sock-puppet management app ... *now on the first month 10 free upvotes* ...

Comment: Just as expected.

Comment: This is the second time in a few weeks that I see someone banned for (allegedly) violating the rules come on meta to try and challenge it. I wonder what those are people thinking! I mean if I were doing something "illegal" and I got caught, I'd probably just shrug it off. Someone might try to contact the staff privately. But to come on a public forum when I know there's evidence against me is really something beyond me.

Comment: This could be a strategy to victimize oneself, but maybe this user didn't realize that it wasn't allowed to vote for other accounts. I've seen much worse behaviour, The "damage" is repaired now. Always assume good intent ... _the first time_

Comment: @Jean I didn't understand how the OP "gained 100 rep association bonus again". Isn't it impossible to get an association bonus twice?

Comment: Also, please explain this: there is no password or extra info to fill in when you're a trusted network user. I never knew this!

Comment: First, you get 100 rep from the source account only once. But new accounts always start at 100. If the account was deleted, and is recreated, it's recreated with 101 rep, not 1. Then there's no password because the authentication is global on SE network. Once you're logged in, you're authenticated for all sites.

Comment: Got it. Multiple uses of the word accounts confused me. At some places, I think profile is the right word.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, my account was deleted as well. What are you talking about? Having registrations on StackExchange communities and StackOverflow at same time is against the rules? I recently joined the reverse engineering community but I don't know how my account broke. Or did you mean the way I have 11 accounts in different StackExchange communities is not allowed because they all start with 100 reputation, not like I care?

Comment: your account was deleted for the same exact reason: Sockpuppet