# My account got deleted/cleared

Tags: support, deleted-users

Yesterday after I finished posting my question/answer to a problem, I closed my computer and went to bed. The next day (today) I come back to Stack Overflow to see that I was logged out. Okay, not that big of a deal maybe my login data was cleared by my browser, I have had that multiple times already. I log in, and I see the message "You are about to create an account from Stack Exchange" or something along those lines. I continue, and my account is cleared.

Reputation, answers, questions, etc. gone. (I didn't really have that much reputation anyway, only 31, but my questions and answers are gone too I think) I checked this question ([My Stack Overflow account is deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397260/my-stack-overflow-account-is-deleted)), and I saw that a moderator had answered with that he had multiple duplicate accounts with similar names, but for me this can't really be the problem, because I only have 1 account (At least I think I only have one, but maybe I have an old account as well.)

It is not necessarily a big deal but I just want to know why my account was 'cleared'

Comment: Can you share a link to  the thing you posted yesterday? Perhaps in your browser history? It's OK if the page is deleted and/or you can't see it. A moderator can still see it. That'd be the easiest way to find your original account and see what happened to it.

Comment: Are these some of your former posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64819748 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64819748 and deleted ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219196 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185462.

Comment: @rene the first two links are the same :)

Comment: @10Rep hmm, there were too much to pick. I got confused obviously.

Comment: rene yes those are my questions, thanks

Answer (score 31):

I believe your account was deleted due to you being under 13 years old. I say "I believe", because we don't keep records which would be able to identify that it was actually *your* account which was deleted.

Within the last 24 hours, I handled a custom moderator flag on a question with an author who had a username the same as the one you are currently using. That flag informed us that the author's profile contained a statement that they were 12 years old. After confirming that such a statement did exist in the question author's profile, I raised an escalation to the CM team, as is [required of moderators under those circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355419/what-are-our-policies-regarding-underage-users). A CM handled the escalation and deleted the account. As part of handling the deletion of the account, an email should have been sent to the email address used to register the account. That email would have explained why the account was deleted.

On a personal level, I think it's **great** that you're interested in programming at a relatively young age. If it's something you enjoy, I strongly encourage you to continue.

Unfortunately for a situation like yours, the existing laws and Stack Overflow's policies do not permit retention of any Personally Identifying Information (PII) for individuals under 13 years old. In addition, the [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) clearly state that all users must be at least 13 years old. As a consequence of those laws and policies, accounts for users who are under 13, or under 16 and in the EU, are deleted. I understand that will be quite frustrating for you and anyone who is under 13 who desires to participate here.

For more information on using Stack Exchange when under the age requirements, you may want to read [Why can't I use Stack Exchange if I'm under 13 years old, and is there any way I can use it legally?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/why-cant-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old-and-is-there-any-way-i)

Comment: Im 13 tho. At the time of making the account i was still 12 but i turned 13 between then and now.

Comment: @Orbyfied Great! I'm not aware if the exact process is documented, but I know it's been possible for another user, who is now above the age cut-off, to have their old questions and answers associated with their new account. I'd suggest using the [contact us link](//stackoverflow.com/company/contact), which is at the bottom of every page, to contact Stack Overflow directly and request that your posts be associated with your new account. As I understand it, it will help to have the email which was sent, but I don't know if that's required. Note: if you're in the EU, you need to be > 16.

Comment: I know that in many cases, moderators can't discuss what happens with other users, so I totally understand if this is one of those cases. Having said that, I just noticed that the user's new account has also been deleted. Is that part of the process to reassociate their old posts with some user account or what's the deal with that?

Comment: @41686d6564 Deleting the new account was not part of the public process I saw with the account I mentioned above where old posts were associated with the new account. I understand your interest and concern, but, yes, responding further would get into information about other users. I can say that I don't believe there's more that 3rd parties can do, or should do, in this case. If any action was taken by the CMs (i.e deletion of the account may have been at the user's request), then the CM's action would have been taken with full knowledge of both this question and the user's comment above.